# IBM Watson Visual Recognition API Key fail - Xcode Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, ibm-watson, visual-recognition

I'm trying to connect to Watson using VisualRecognitionV3.framework.

The framework's compiled fine (via Carthage), and I think I've got the Service Credentials configured correctly, but when I compile Xcode to the simulator I get an invalid-api-key error.

Has anyone experienced the same issues?
What am I doing wrong?

```
private let apiKey = "Xn5DUtQU8WzgFTL9qNEFwBjxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    private let classifierId = "DefaultCustomModel_2051029379"
    private let version = "2018-07-01"
    var visualRecognition: VisualRecognition!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.visualRecognition = VisualRecognition(apiKey: apiKey, version: version)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let localModels = try? visualRecognition.listLocalModels()
        if let models = localModels, models.contains(self.classifierId)  {
            print("local model found")
        } else {
            self.updateModel()
        }
    }
```

Xcode Error:

```
Error Domain=com.ibm.watson.developer-cloud.VisualRecognitionV3 Code=403 "ERROR: invalid-api-key" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=ERROR: invalid-api-key}
```

Watson configuration screenshot:
[Watson Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iBHn.png)

Comment: I think you need to use IAM instead. https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/swift-sdk#authentication

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your VisualRecognition using another initializer, like the following

```
let visualRecognition = VisualRecognition(version: version, apiKey: apiKey, iamUrl: nil)
```

The difference is that you will need to call this 3 argument-ed constructor with the third argument, i.e. the iamUrl, even though you make it nil and anything else is the same. This tells the VisualRecognition class to authenticate your app using the IAM.

The git documentation is very confusing, which says in here https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/swift-sdk#visual-recognition

> Note: a different initializer is used for authentication with instances created before May 23, 2018:

Which means the old way should just work, **UNLESS**, they made a mistake and they actually mean **AFTER** May 23, 2018

Anyways, if you try it should just work. I was having this issue 30 mins before writing this answer.

Comment: thanks @Joe . yep, got it authenticating by correctly ordering instance initializers.